# Reverse proxy serving html linked content as 404

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've set up this reverse proxy to route a simple web page served on a port (say 61185).
Instead of querying `example.net:61185`, i'd like to have the same behavior with `example.net/listing`

Here's the config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.net;
  location /listing {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:61185/;
  }
}
```

The html loads fine, but when fetching the css linked inside it I get a 404.
I noticed the URI is `http://example.net/styling.css`, **how can I make it so that the css is also fetched with the `/listing` suffix?**

Comment: Then add another `location` section to forward `.css` requests.

Comment: I simplified the example, isn't there a way to do that for all linked content in the page?
Ideally I'd like this to be extensible to other more complex pages.

Comment: If you are writing the web app/page, please go to Stack Overflow and learn how to design from day 1 to work with reverse proxy. Then you don’t need too many rules.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing is that the URLs for the linked CSS resources in the HTML page are not being rewritten to include the /listing prefix, so the browser is requesting them from the wrong location.
Try this block of code:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.net;
  location /listing {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:61185/listing;
    proxy_redirect /listing /;
  }
}
```